# Mssql query exec returns error

Tags: php, sql-server, driver, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm connected to a sybase db through php's mssql driver.

When I run this sql query:

```
$result = mssql_query("exec taxKM $rate, $var, $days, $discount, $distance, $inDate, $outDate, null", $cnx);
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: mssql_query(): message: ASA Error -188: Not enough values for host variables (severity 16)
```

I'm following the `taxKM` procedure specs.

It seems there are missing values, isn't it?

But if I'm following the specs, it has to do with wrong function specs?

Comment: No, that was a typo, Michael.

Comment: You may want to inspect the procedure to make sure it matches the specs.  `sp_helptext taxKM` should give you the information.

Answer (score 1):

I *guess* you have to properly quote the non-numeric procedure-arguments in the string , so instead of

```
mssql_query("exec taxKM $rate, $var, $days, $discount, $distance, $inDate, $outDate, null", $cnx)
```

try this

```
mssql_query("exec taxKM $rate, '$var', $days, '$discount', $distance, '$inDate', '$outDate', null", $cnx)
```

or similar

Aside from that, I don't know if ASA - Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere can be accessed with the php-mssql driver.

Comment: If I try to access with the sybase driver I get the same result. And quoting non-numeric values has no efect on the result.

Comment: maybe your procedure expects even more variables, then? - Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127364/sql-anywhere-query-error-not-enough-values-for-host-variables